# Django ManyToManyField error object has no attribute 'location_set'

Tags: django, django-models

This seems like a really trivial question, but it is killing me.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField("Location", max_length=30)
    [...]

class Person(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=50)
    [...]
    location = models.ManyToManyField('Location')
```

From the shell:

```
>>> from mysite.myapp.models import *
>>> p = Person.objects.get(id=1)
>>> p
<Person: bob >
>>> l = Location(place='123 Main')
>>> p.location_set.add(l)
>>> p.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'location_set'
```

I'm really not seeing what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be using `p.location.add()`? `location_set` or `<modelname>_set` is the default name for the [***reverse*** lookup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for that model.

Answer (score 1):

`location_set` would be the default name for a backward relation, however since you've defined the `ManyToManyField` on the `Person` model, you can access the related manager via the field name:

```
p.location.add(l)
```

With this in mind, it makes more sense to name the `ManyToManyField` as a pluralised noun, e.g.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=50)
    [...]
    locations = models.ManyToManyField('Location')
```

Also, from memory, when you try to add model instances to a many-to-many relationship, the instance must be saved prior to adding.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't realize there was a distinction between "forward" and "backwards". Is there a reason for that? Obviously, mapping tables themselves don't create any such "directionality".

Comment: That's correct, but the field itself does represent one 'end' of the relationship. The backward relation from `Location` to `Person` in this case is `person_set`

Comment: I get that, and I appreciate the help. Django is heavy on "should" - it makes things easy if you do it their way. I guess what I'm asking is, why is there a class-enforced difference in, I guess, the vector of the relationship here? Most of the design decisions make sense to me - this one doesn't, which is probably more about me than the framework, but...

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Are you saying that you think the backward relation should be named 'people' or something?