# Django ManyToMany field returns error 'object has no attribute'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many

There are similar posts to this like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616105/django-manytomanyfield-error-object-has-no-attribute-location-set), but none of them seem to answer my question.  I am trying to add something to a `ManyToMany` Field in Django using `ModelForms`, but I keep getting an error.  My code looks something like:

models.py:

```
class LineSection(models.Model):
    ...
class Line(models.Model):
    line_id = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(LineSection)
class LineForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = [...,'sections']
```

views.py:

```
partialLine = Line(user=1001)
line = LineForm(request.POST.copy(), instance=partialLine)
...
newSect = Section(sect_id=sectId,
    point_list=sect['point_list'],
    ...)
try:
    newSect.save()
    line.sections.add(newSect)
except Exception as e: ...
```

I get the error:

> 'LineForm' object has no attribute 'sections'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as the error says: `line` is an instance of `LineForm`, not `Line`. You need to save the form object at some point to get the actual updated model instance:

```
line_obj = line.save()
```

although you should probably rename the confusing `line` object.

Comment: Thank you!  I think that works.  (Yeah, the variable names are different in my project, but I thought without context these might actually be easier...I guess not.)

Comment: Do I have to do `line_obj.save()` after the `add()`?

Comment: No, because add only affects the through table, not the line instance itself.